# Comparing two uuids in Node.js

Tags: node.js, cassandra, comparison, uuid

I have a question I was not able to find any answer with my research on the web. I work on a web application in Node.js and Cassandra. I'm currently working on a notification system and I have to compare two uuids to make sure I don't send a notification to the people who make the original action ( which provoke the notification ).

The problem is that, when I compare two uuids which are supposed to be equals, I always get a false value.

Here is the example of code I'm currently working on :

```
console.log('user_id :', user_id.user_id);
console.log("user id of the current user :", this.user_id);

console.log(user_id.user_id == this.user_id);
console.log(user_id.user_id === this.user_id);
```

And here is the display of the result :

```
user_id : Uuid: 29f1227d-58dd-4ddb-b0fa-19b7fc02fbe8
user id of the current user : Uuid: 29f1227d-58dd-4ddb-b0fa-19b7fc02fbe8
false
false
user_id : Uuid: c8f9c196-2d63-4cf0-b388-f11bfb1a476b
user id of the current user : Uuid: 29f1227d-58dd-4ddb-b0fa-19b7fc02fbe8
false
false
```

As you can see, the first uuids are supposed to be the same. They are generated with the uuid library inside the nodejs cassandra driver. 
I don't understand why I can not compare them when I am able to make any request on my Cassandra database with a uuid specified.

If someone could help me, it will be a great pleasure !

Comment: What is `typeof user_id.user_id` and `typeof this.user_id`? I'm betting they are (different) objects and not strings. The reasoning is that the ids are prefixed with `Uuid: ` in the output, which may be coming from the object's `toString()` implementation.

Comment: Indeed the user_id and this.user_id are both different objects, that's why a simple === was not enough to compare them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Ary mentioned, the contents are the same but the addresses are not, so the comparison returns false.

The cassandra-driver's UUID object provides an equals function which compares the raw hex string of the contents of the UUID that you could use for this:

```
> var uuid1 = uuid.fromString('29f1227d-58dd-4ddb-b0fa-19b7fc02fbe8')
> var uuid2 = uuid.fromString('29f1227d-58dd-4ddb-b0fa-19b7fc02fbe8')
> uuid1 == uuid2
false
> uuid1 === uuid2
false
> uuid1.equals(uuid2)
true
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I didn't know of the equals method from the cassandra-driver's UUID object. Indeed if I compare them with this method it returns the result expected.

Answer (score 1):

The content is the same but their addresses should not be.
If your comparaison returns false it may be your variables are Object type.

Comment: It's true as you said they are both objects that's why I could not compare them with a simple '==='.

Answer (score 1):

I do something like this, and it works:

```
// assuming there are 2 uuids, uuidOne uuidTwo  
uuidOne.toString() === uuidTwo.toString()
```

Answer (score -1):

It looks like your user_id is actually an object "containing" a Uuid, not the Uuid itself. The user_id objects are not the same, but they contain the same data.

Try comparing the Uuid's directly like:

```
console.log(user_id.user_id.Uuid == this.user_id.Uuid);
console.log(user_id.user_id.Uuid === this.user_id.Uuid);
```

Comment: The display of 'user_id' and 'this.user_id' is this way only because they are objects. So even if it shows 'Uuid : value', it is just a display, Uuid is not a property of the object so 'user_id.user_id.Uuid' and 'this.user_id.Uuid' return 'undefined'.